# How to restrict loading of lazy loaded module till resolving some data from api in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lazy-loading

I have a lazy loaded module. I want to load some data before the module load. I tried app_initializer but it didn't work because i have already an app_initializer in AppModule. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an Resolver that will handle your data before the module will load and navigate to your specific route as that loaded completly

resolver

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { APIService } from './api.service';

import { Resolve } from '@angular/router';

import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class APIResolver implements Resolve<any> {
constructor(private apiService: APIService) {}

 resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
  return this.apiService.getItems(route.params.date);
  }
}
```

in your route

```
{
 path: 'items/:date',
 component: ItemsComponent,
 resolve: { items: APIResolver }
}
```

and to acces the resolved data in the desired component

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
items: any[];

ngOnInit() {
 this.items= this.route.snapshot.data.items;
}
```

using a component with a resolver in a given module will not init that module until all the data is resolved

you can check also https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve

Comment: I think this is not the good way to achieve this. Because Inside the lazyloaded module there might be multiple routes. 
what should i do in such case, use route resolver in every route and handle the resolved data in every routing component?

Comment: well, the resolver will be triggered only if you navigate to that route that has a resolver. you don't need to use a resolver on all routes. If you want  the data to be loaded after the navigation on the route you can still fetch data and use a placeholder until the data is fetched, like a spinner or a placeholder. You subscribe to it and when you have the result you remove the placeholder or the spinner